# Import CSV separated by semicolons and delimited by quotes

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I need your help to solve a problem of importing .cv local files to a `MariaDB 10.3` database. On my server I am running PHP7.2.

To import use a PHP script with the following statement:

```
exec("mysql -u Myuser -pMySrtongPassword -e \"USE MyDatabase;
TRUNCATE MyTable;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/html/upload/file.csv' IGNORE  INTO TABLE MyTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES ;\"; ");
```

This works well for most of the `.csv` files that I need to import. However, I have some `.csv` files that have the following format:

```
"field1"; "field2"; ..... "fieldN";
```

They are separated by semicolons and delimited by quotes.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to import these files correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'` to the `LOAD DATA

```
TRUNCATE MyTable;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/html/upload/file.csv' IGNORE  INTO TABLE MyTable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES ;
```

Comment: Thanks,

I just add "OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' and work fine in MySQL CLI but in PHP script I receive the following error in :

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' LINES TERMINATED BY' at line 3 sh: -c: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' sh: -c: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I think the problem is in the way of concatenating '\"' inside the php exec command. Any ideas?

Comment: the problem is you have to esccape it for the shell com and and mysql, so you should try '\\\"'

Comment: that's it. You save my day! Thanks